# Django: create Index: non-unique, multiple column

Tags: mysql, django, indexing

Given the following model, I want to index the fields (sequence,stock)

```py
class QuoteModel(models.Model):  
    quotedate =  models.DateField()  
    high = models.FloatField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    low  = models.FloatField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    close  = models.FloatField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    closeadj  = models.FloatField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    volume  = models.IntegerField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    stock  = models.IntegerField(db_index=True) #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    open  = models.FloatField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
    sequence = models.IntegerField() #(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
```

This index should be non-unique - in mysql it should be something like:

```
create index ndx_1 on model_quotemodel(sequence,stock);
```

The only Django workaround I know of is creating an "sql" file that will be executed by django upon table creation. So, I created a "stockmodel.sql" containing the following query (same as above:)

```
create index ndx_1 on model_quotemodel(sequence,stock);
```

Is there any "cleaner" way of doing it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of Django 1.5, you can use the [`Meta.index_together` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#index-together):

```
class QuoteModel(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ("sequence", "stock"),
        ]
```

(note: the original answer from 2009 said it was not possible to index multiple fields; it has since been replaced)

Comment: I am not sure if this answer really addresses non-primary key composite keys?  Doesn't seem to.

Comment: This is not at all what the question is looking for. need non-unique, non-primary, composite keys.

Comment: I don't think the comments above are relevant to the current answer... it seems from the docs that `index_together` _does_ provide non-unique, non-primary composite index

Comment: 2020 update: [`indexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes).

Comment: The newer [`indexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes) option provides more functionality than `index_together`. `index_together` [was deprecated in Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together).

Answer (score 24):

There is a ticket for this feature. Take a look http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5805

You may apply the patch from this ticket yourself.

**UPDATE**

It's now in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together

Answer (score 17):

To follow on from the accepted answer, if you are using [South](http://south.aeracode.org), you can easily add a composite key as follows:

manage.py schemamigration your_app_name name_for_migration --add-index ModelName.first_field_in_index

You can then edit the generated migration file to add the additional fields into the one index (you'll see it's just a list of field names that's needed).

Don't forget to update the reverse migration as well as the forward one.

Answer (score 16):

It is index_together in django 1.5

See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#index-together

Answer (score 12):

The **index_together** feature could be deprecated in the futur.

You should use [indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes) option instead of **index_together**.

Example of **indexes** option :

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
            models.Index(fields=['first_name'], name='first_name_idx'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 11):

[`unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) might be what you are looking for. Just put it in your `Meta` class inside your model.

Comment: he asked for index_together. you told him unique_together. not what he asked.

Comment: Although this isn't answer for this question, this helped me while searching exactly for multiple column unique index. So, thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's a bit of confusion between "unique index" and "unique constraint".. anyways, I found this question looking for the unique constraint, too.. +1

Answer (score 5):

Update for 2022:

The newer [`indexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes) option provides more functionality than `index_together`. `index_together` [was deprecated in Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together).

[Usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes):

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
            models.Index(fields=['first_name'], name='first_name_idx'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that as of Django 1.11 there is a new feature, Options.indexes, which will allow you to specify the indexes to create:

[Django Options.indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes)